# What's the reference for CSS translation function?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am wondering what is the reference position for css translation function.

for example, if I have a:

```css
p {
    transform:translate(100px,100px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p> Try! </p>
</div>
```

in firefox developer tool, you could see a green and a blue "box", the green one is the reference position, and the blue is the object's real position.

But the reference one is neither at the top-left corner of the window nor of the object's parent. And I am sure I don't have any property like padding and margin.

Comment: The snippet part seems not work....

Comment: There is no `translation` property in CSS. Did you mean `transform`, `translate`, or `transition`?

Comment: CSS doesn't have functions or anything called "Translation". It has `translate` which is a possible value of the `transform` property.

Comment: should be `transform: translate(100px, 100px)`

Comment: [**This**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and [**This**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/)

Comment: Oh, sorry. It should be transform: translate(100px, 100px).  Er..I am sorry for the mistake. My question is about what's the reference for the '100px'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `translate` transform-function offsets the element it is applied to from the space it would normally occupy on the page, with the first value representing the horizontal offset and the second the vertical offset. Consider the following group of elements, where `translate` has been applied to the 3rd one, moving it left `10px` and down `5px`:

```css
body{
  color:#fff;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:0;
  text-align:center;
}
p{
  background:#000;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:14px;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px;
}
p:nth-of-type(3){
  background:#090;
  transform:translate(10px,5px);
}
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>
<p>A little more text</p>
<p>This text is transformed</p>
<p>This paragraph isn't</p>
<p>Nor is this last one</p>
```

Comment: Thx! but if I don't have any padding or margin, where should be the inital place? (0 0)?

Comment: And for my case, the initial position seems not even in its parent. At least the left is the same as the window.

Comment: The first child element of a parent element that does not have any margins or `padding` applied would normally have an initial position of `0px,0px`, yes. In the example in your question, you're applying the transformation to the first child of the first child of the `body` element so the origin point is the top left of the browser window (plus the default margins on the `body`).

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
p {
   transform: translate(100px, 100px);
}
```

Working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/hhhotv8x/

The top left corner is the position (0, 0)
Defining a translation is based on the top left position of the container. So, the definition is implicit, in every case, it would be "0,0", because it depends of the container.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: it's the top left corner (including  margin) of the parent element.

---

It's the [transformation matrix](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformation-matrix):

> A matrix that defines the mathematical mapping from one **coordinate system** into another. It is computed from the values of the transform and transform-origin properties as described [below](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformation-matrix-computation).

According to [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformation-matrix-computation):

> The transformation matrix is computed from the transform and
>   transform-origin properties as follows:
>
> - Start with the identity matrix.
> - Translate by the computed X, Y and Z
>     values of transform-origin
> - Multiply by each of the transform functions
>     in transform property from left to right
> - Translate by the negated
>     computed X, Y and Z values of transform-origin

In this case, you are using `translate` so the `transform-origin` does not affect the transformed element's position.

That means it is being translated from the **coordinate system** of the `<div id="container">` element which is the [top left corner `(0,0)` of the bounding box](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#propdef-transform-origin).

> **`<length>`**
>
> A length value gives a fixed length as the offset. The value for the horizontal and vertical offset represent an offset from the top left corner of the bounding box.

[image]

So if you add margin to the `#container` the position of the `<p>` will change.

```css
#container {
    margin: 20px;
}
p {
    transform:translate(100px,100px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p> Try! </p>
</div>
```